# How to push rows of an existing dataframe to a new dataframe based on a condition?

Tags: python, pandas

I currently have a dataframe with the elevation information for houses. I would like to separate this into different dataframes based on a condition. I have the following:

```
minor = data[data.NAVD88 <= 5]
moderate = data[data.NAVD88 > 5] and data[data.NAVD88 < 7]
major = data[data.NAVD88 >= 7]
```

However, the moderate line doesn't seem to work, and I get the following error:

```
The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

What is the correct syntax to have this work properly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use botwise `and` by `&` and because priority precedence add `()` for chained boolean masks:

```
minor = data[data.NAVD88 <= 5]
moderate = data[(data.NAVD88 > 5) & (data.NAVD88 < 7)]
major = data[data.NAVD88 >= 7]
```